# Laravel - error in code which I cannot see

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel. I have created a database and put some records (cards) into the database. So far, this works fine.

I have a CardsController with the following code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CardsController extends Controller
{
    public function index() 
    {
        $cards = DB::table('cards')->get();
        return view ('cards.index', compact('cards'));
    }
}
```

When I run it I get this error:

> FatalErrorException in b3313739fb5d5f08e44d77a431f809ec37961a7b.php
>   line 11: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '('
>
> in b3313739fb5d5f08e44d77a431f809ec37961a7b.php line 11
>
> Line 11 is class CardsController extends Controller

How can I fix this?

Comment: This error is in your view page, not in a controller. Post the code of your `index.blade.php` file. Maybe I can help you.

Comment: As previous comment the error is in the view page at `cards/index.blade.php` and the compiled file is stored in `storage/framework/views/b3313739fb5d5f08e44d77a431f809ec37961a7b.php`.

Comment: Thanks guys. The page that it calls should be dashboard,blade.php and here is a link to it http://www.jimelliott.co.uk/laravel/dashboard.blade.php